# Keep getting "Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "songs"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following model class:

```
# Song Model
class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='songs')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.title + ' ' + self.artist

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)
```

My serializers

```
class SongSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'artist', 'content')
        model = Song


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    songs = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True, read_only=True,
        view_name='songs'
        )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

and my views

```
class SongViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Song.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SongSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

I am trying to get the list of songs but I keep getting this error
ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "songs"

This has been working with [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)
but not as it is now.

routes file for reference:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'songs', views.SongViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to make it work with

```
view_name='song-detail'
```

If anyone wants to explain the why of how it works, please feel free

Answer (score 0):

I'm total newbie in Django but I've faced with the same issue. I suppose that because of router prefix param is not the view name.

[Documentation for the router](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage) says:

> The example above would generate the following URL patterns:
>
> URL pattern: ^users/$ Name: 'user-list'
>   URL pattern: ^users/{pk}/$ Name: 'user-detail'
>   URL pattern: ^accounts/$ Name: 'account-list'
>   URL pattern: ^accounts/{pk}/$ Name: 'account-detail'

[Documentation for the serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield) says:

> **view_name** - The view name that should be used as the target of the relationship. If you're using the standard router classes this will be a string with the format 
>   `<modelname>-detail`. required.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DefaultRouter
you can try change basename='song'

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
router = DefaultRouter()

router.register('song', views.SongViewset, basename='song')
```